# How can I create a variable that can only change its value if the new value to be assigned to it meets a predefined condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, constants

Image you have a **global variable** named `window.whatever`. Is it possible to prevent anyone to change its type AND its value if the new value you want to store into it doesn't meet some condition?

For example, I don't want my variable to be changed if it doesn't start with 'https://'.

In this case,
`window.whatever = "Hello"` and `window.whatever = 15` would throw an error but `window.whatever = "https://example.com/"` would work fine.

Maybe `Object.defineProperty` will fix it but I don't know how.

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'whatever', {
  writable: true, //here I want to add a sort of condition
});
```

I tried this:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window,'whatever',{
    set:function(x){
        if (x.startsWith('https://')) this.whatever= x}
})
```

but when I do `window.whatever = "https://example.com"` it says :`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` and it's still undefined

Comment: Wouldn't you just need a setter that performs your test(s)?

Comment: I would suggest reading [MDN's documentation on how `defineProperty` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Custom_Setters_and_Getters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Providing a better solution. In the previous one, `__globalVar` wasn't hidden and you could access it directly (read/write). This is probably not the best idea, so here's a better way:

```js
(function () {
  let privateValue = "Hello";
  Object.defineProperty(window, "whatever", {
    get: function () {
      console.log("in getter");
      return privateValue;
    },
    set: function (val) {
      console.log("in setter");
      if (typeof val === "string" && val.startsWith("https://")) {
        privateValue = val;
      } else {
        throw "Invalid whatever";
      }
    },
  });
})();

console.log(window.whatever);
window.whatever = "https://stackoverflow.com";
console.log(window.whatever);
window.whatever = "lalala123";
console.log(window.whatever);
```

Now `privateValue` actually is private.

---

Does something like this work for you? I think it behaves like you described.

```js
let __globalVar = 'Hello';
Object.defineProperty(window, 'whatever', {
 get() {
  console.log('in getter');
    return __globalVar;
  },
 set(val) {
        // put your logic here
        console.log('in setter');
        if( val.startsWith("https://") ) {
            __globalVar = val;
       } else {
            throw "Invalid whatever"
        }
    }
})

console.log(window.whatever);
window.whatever = "https://google.com";
console.log(window.whatever);
window.whatever = "lalala123";
console.log(window.whatever);
```

Comment: @eagertolearnmore I updated my answer with a slightly better solution.